# How to prevent my stacked series from being in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, indexing, highcharts, series, stacked

I tried an [example of stacked series on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-stacking-line/) but according to me, series are reversed when stacked:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
        }]
    });
});
```

The first line in blue should be drawn first (January : 29.9), and the second should be added to this one (January : 29.9 + 144 = 173.9 ).

Is there a way to get series in the right order when they are stacked?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can change order by index parameter which can be set in serie.

http://jsfiddle.net/KLttA/

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        index:1
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        index:0
    }]
```

Comment: I'll try it and add `legend: { reversed: true }` to get it in the right order too. Thanks !

Comment: Sebastian, would you know how to set a series index value in c#?

Comment: Honestly im not familair with c#, but it is a object in javascript, so you need to familari with returning JSON in c# and then use in JS>

Comment: While @lionel's answer is better for just getting the stacks in the correct order, this is still very useful in other cases (like fixing the order of non-stacked multiple series in bar charts).

Comment: This wouldn't work when using chart.addSeries(). zIndex solves this problem.

Comment: If you're using stacks this may get additionally confusing because you'll have sub-ordering within your stacks. I think the legend will then be in the right order for stacks, but then the stacks will not be in reverse order. I haven't yet found a way around this besides living with letting the second stack's legend sit in front of the first stack's legend. They will draw like: `{stack1: [a,b,c], stack2: [d]}` but the legend will be like: `[d, a, b, c]`. The actual storage will be like: `[a=2, b=1, c=0, d=3]` if you want to keep `d` drawing after stack `[a,b,c]` ‍♂️

Answer (score 43):

Since this was the top result in google, maybe this saves time for some:

The `yAxis` has a `reversedStacks` parameter (since version 3.0.10), which is `true` by default. To build stacks from bottom up, set this to `false`. Legend  and shared tooltip item order remain correct this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/r5upptLo/

Comment: API docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.reversedStacks

I'd expect false to be the default..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the serie's ***legendIndex*** parameter : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.legendIndex

Comment: Thanks for posting this additional detail - legendIndex is actually what I was after (not index as thats set by the order).

Comment: hm according to the docs legendIndex is only for pie charts and the example given by the OP is a line chart

Comment: Welp. Nevermind. Just tried it and it works for all chart types. Docs need updating I guess

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is by adding `.reverse()` to the end of the series array, see example at http://jsfiddle.net/sq9u6q5n/ .

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is `reversed` in xAxis or yAxis. I tried `reversedStacks` but it didn't work and after looking at the documentation, I couldn't find it so assuming that it has been replaced with `reversed`.

Comment: `reversed` does something completely different. It reverses the whole axis, e.g. if it previously went from `0` on the left to `100` on the right, `0` is now on the right and the bars (if it's a bar chart) start from the right.

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as Lionel's (except that one has the correct value for the property) from several months earlier.